# No resource type specified

Tags: java, android, manifest

I need help, i am getting this error:

> Error:(25, 36) No resource type specified (at 'fullBackupContent' with value '@android:').
>   Error:(25, 36) No resource type specified (at 'fullBackupContent' with value '@android:').
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

And Everytime i delete 'fullBackupContent' it appears again, What is the cause?. This is my manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="24" />

<protected-broadcast android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" />

<application
    android:name="com.example.user.FaceJam.Pruebaloginapp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:fullBackupContent="@android:"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_facejam"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/com_facebook_activity_theme" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.user.FaceJam.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.example.user.FaceJam.MainActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.user.FaceJam.LoginActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.user.FaceJam.DashBoardActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
        android:exported="true" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabMainActivity" />
</application>
```

Comment: Hope this helps: [Configure Data Backup](https://developer.android.com/training/backup/autosyncapi.html#configuring)

Comment: I don't understand why you have `"@android:"`

Comment: I was experimenting with the fullbackup but then this happened, the weird part is that everytime i try to delete something from the AndroidManifest and click Build, the line i deleted appears again!!!

Comment: Did you try close android studio and use an external text editor for change the line?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the file you are editing isn't a *generated* one. Try to find the main `AndroidManifest.xml` which should be the one on the top directory of your app source and edit *that* file.